# Is it possible to use MyBatis to issue DDL?

Tags: java, mybatis

For example, is it possible to use MyBatis to issue DDL(`Alter table, Drop table`) to database? For example, modify the table schema using alter table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. See this [thread](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Dynamically-Create-Tables-using-MYBATIS-td3397630.html)

You would do something like :

```
<update id="createNewTable" parameterType="String" > 

    #{value}; 

</update >
```

Where the parameter is your 'create table' statement, using #{value} means your parameter will not be escaped.

If you just want to set the table name, you would do:

```
<update id="createNewTable" parameterType="String" > 

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS #{value} ( 
            id             INT UNSIGNED        AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

</update >
```

Here is nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18849402/1878022) for alter